# Why CONSTANT value in class is changed?

Tags: ruby

I have a class like this:

```
class Example
  DEFAULT_VALUE = {
      'first_key': ['a', 'b'],
      'second_key': 'c'
  }

  def append_new_value(value)
    default_value_copy = DEFAULT_VALUE
    default_value_copy[:first_key] << value
    puts "default_value_copy: #{default_value_copy}"
    puts "DEFAULT_VALUE: #{DEFAULT_VALUE}"
  end
end

example = Example.new
example.append_new_value('d')
example.append_new_value('e')
```

The results are:

```
default_value_copy: {:first_key=>["a", "b", "d"], :second_key=>"c"}
DEFAULT_VALUE: {:first_key=>["a", "b", "d"], :second_key=>"c"}
default_value_copy: {:first_key=>["a", "b", "d", "e"], :second_key=>"c"}
DEFAULT_VALUE: {:first_key=>["a", "b", "d", "e"], :second_key=>"c"}
```

As I understood before, the value of DEFAULT_VALUE should not be changed after calling `append_new_value` method.

Could you guys help me to explain about this case?

Comment: The constant doesn't change. The object the constant references does. Ruby is not a purely functional language, objects are allowed to change.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Ruby does not have the notion of constants like you would expect from other languages. Ruby constants can change values. If you want to specify that an object should not be mutated in Ruby you must use the [Object#freeze](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-freeze) method on it.

Then, there is the matter of Ruby passing method arguments by reference or by value. You could say that Ruby is pass-by-value in the traditional sense. However in Ruby all variables are references to objects, so if you pass an object to a method it will indeed get mutated.

If you're looking for quick wins in immutability, check out [Object#dup](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-dup).

Comment: `dup` only creates a shallow copy, i.e. `DEFAULT_VALUE[:first_key]` and `DEFAULT_VALUE.dup[:first_key]` still refer to the same array.

Comment: @Stefan you are right. Not applicable in this example, I just mentioned it for reference.